# Loop through array in react onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I have an array of objects. How can I loop through this array on click?

```
test = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
 {this.state.test.map(function(i){
     return <span> {i} </span>
  })}
```

I would normally loop through like this in react but this prints them all out at once. How can I display 'a' on the page and then the next time i click it, I display 'b' so on until the end of the array?

I need a function that can tell where I am in the array and display that on the page at the right moment

Answer (score 2):

You could implement e.g. a counter variable and use `Array#slice` to show specified amount of elements inside the `test` array.

**[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/Wrw0Em4E)**

```
import React from "react";

export default class Hello extends React.Component {
  state = {
    test: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    index: 0
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    let i = this.state.index < this.state.test.length ? this.state.index += 1 : 0;
    this.setState({ index: i });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.test.slice(0, this.state.index).map(v => {
          return (
            <span>{v}</span>
          );
        })}
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit**: I was playing with it and actually I got even a better solution, which allows you to avoid re-looping `Array#map` on every render, with little help of `hidden` attribute. Also we are getting rid of the `Array#slice` function.

**[Improved codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/mZ1DLXZY3)**

`app.js`

```
{this.state.test.map((v, i) => {
  return (
    <span hidden={i >= this.state.index}>{v}</span>
  );
})}
```

And the `Span.js` component:

```
<span hidden={this.props.hidden}>
  {this.props.v}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

set initial index at your state first, then use that index as index array in span. next make some function to handle the increment, simply put it like this

```
const switchNinjaHandler = () => {
let looper = ++this.state.index % this.state.test.length;
setState({
  ...personsState, // WE SHOULD ALWAYS GIVE THE EXCACT INITIAL STATE VALUE, THIS IS WHERE SPREAD COMING HANDY
  this.index : looper,
});
```

to display

```
return ( <div> {this.state.test[this.index]} </div> )
```